# Composer install, segmentation fault

Tags: php, macos, symfony, composer-php

I can't get the command composer install to run. All I get is an instant fail with a segmentation error, php problem?

- Brand new MacBook Prop
- OS - Mojave 10.14.5
- PHP - 7.3.7
- Symfony - 4.6.0
- PHP was installed using brew, it is the current stable version.
- Symfony was installed from their website, using there installer via curl.
- Composer I have downloaded locally for the project.

Output of componser install:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file

Prefetching 96 packages  
  - Downloading (0%)[1]    4278 segmentation fault  composer install
```

Output of composer -vvv install:

[Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/4gRWEzYK)

I have managed to succeed in getting this running on Manjaro and Ubunutu, running PHP 7.3.7.

Most reliable source of info comes [from this issue on github](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7139), indicating that it's a PHP issue, likely version/build issue. My project relies on PHP 7.2^.

**UPDATE** - Checked with `brew install php@7.2`. Same issue.

**UPDATE 2** - [Found this thread](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/segmentation-fault-on-mojave-http24-php56/3043/7), tried solution and no luck

**UPDATE 3** - I ran `composer install` with the `--no-plugins` flag, it is now downloading the dependencies. I also ran `clear-cache` before this, I am not sure if they worked hand in hand or if it's just `--no-plugins`. This points to one of my PHP plugins that are installed by default as causing an issue with memory violation. Which one? Who knows.

**UPDATE 4** - Was still not working after downloads finished, I had to again run `composer install` without the `--no-plugin` flag. Seems to be working.

Comment: Probably is a memory violation. Check is you are using xdebug and disable it. And close other programs that you can.

Comment: No xdebug. I have tried doing it straight from a reboot.

Comment: Try removing the symfony web server from the composer file and see if it's a package specific issue.

Comment: what about opcache? check the value of opcache.enable_cli

Comment: @MithrandirBen location of that flag? I have disabled opcache altogether in `/usr/local/etc/php*/conf.d/ext-opcache.init`

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found the solution. Hopefully this helps someone:

I ran `composer install` with the `--no-plugins` flag.

After download finished, I had to again run `composer install` without the `--no-plugins` flag.

EDIT: This was fine and dandy until other issues came to light when adding dependencies! Turns out curl is the problem.

To solve,

```
brew remove curl-openssl --ignore-dependencies curl-openssl
brew install curl-ssl
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I compiled PHP 7.4.x from source and started running into this issue, and adding `--no-plugins` solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was solved when I increased the memory limit. The `php.ini` had the limit set to 256MB however, I found out that some ini installed by brew has overridden that limit and forced it to be 128MB.

I will list the path I followed to fix my issue below.

**Step 1** — figure out the actual memory limit:

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
```

**Step 2** — find used `php.ini` file path:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

The `memory_limit` from step 1 did not match the `memory_limit` in the file I located from step 2.

I looked further and found the following config file which PHP loads, turned out to be overriding the `memory_limit` to 128MB:

`/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`

**Step 3** — I disabled it:

```sh
mv /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini.bak
```

Then finally confirmed that step 1 returns the correct `memory_limit` I set, which is 256MB.

Hope it helps those who have the same issue.

**NOTE:** your installation path will probably be different, I put examples here that matched my case, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

i using composer 2.x and cause this problem
my coworker helps me solve this by:

composer self-update --1

then

composer update
or
composer dump-autoload

if you want composer back to 2.x:

composer self-update --rollback

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after disabling the xdebug extension in php.ini and having file opcache enabled (`opcache.enable_cli = 1` and `opcache.file_cache` set to a local directory). It seems those opcache files have to be deleted when xdebug is disabled otherwise any execution of cached php files will lead to a segmentation fault (this is with PHP 7.4.10).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the PHP version from php 7.3 to 7.4
now its working  for me

Answer (score 0):

if none of the solution works try disabling (if your have enabled opcache for cli)
`opcache.enable_cli=1` in your `php.ini`.

[Here's](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6052) reference .

Answer (score 0):

Memory fault. This can occur if you have a folder or services running that composer is also trying to use. Make sure you have any such folder windows and apps closed prior to running composer.